# Wlan0 in kali linux VM not showing up

Tags: linux

Can someone help me?
I have installed a VM and i'm trying to use kali linux but if i type sudo ifconfig -a it shows only eth0 and lo but what i want is for it to show me wlan0 or smth. I have read some posts that talk about a wirless card but doesn't the laptop have one itself?

Comment: I gave you the correct answer. Please follow up.  Look at the Help Tour and see how to accept an answer. Too many Kali users do NOT follow up.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone help me? I have installed a VM and i'm trying to use kali
> linux

What you see is entirely normal. Any VM uses the VM App networking, and that is always a wired network.

If you wish to use Wireless in your VM, you need a compliant wireless USB card.  Panda is a good choice.  Try that. It works for me on my Kali 2023.2 VM.

You need to use USB Pass Through to see it.